# Can browse & curl but not ping

Tags: macos, curl, ping

while trying to install Elasticsearch, I got into a problem. I am able to browse http://packages.elasticsearch.org but not able to install it from their packages. Probed further & found that `ping http://packages.elasticsearch.org` results in `unable to resolve` error but `curl http://packages.elasticsearch.org` works ok.

ping to few sites like http://www.yahoo.com but not http://www.google.com (but again curl and browsing is ok)

I'm not using any proxy; I'm on Mac Yosemite.

How do I troubleshoot & resolve?

Thank you,
Joseph